# Update only one field from VF page to opportunity after calling approval process dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process

I have an approval process on opportunity where i'm updating some fields in opportunity. Im calling this approval process dynamically using apex code where fields are updated after calling approval process but I have a custom picklist field on opportunity which is modified on VF page. I need to update single value from VF page to opportunity detail page. When im using update dml operation the other values are overriding with VF page values which im getting from opportunity page. I want only one value to be updated in opportunity.

apex class:

```
public PageReference Reject()
    {

    if(objOpp.Reopened_Reason__c == '--None--'||String.isBlank(objOpp.Reopened_Reason__c))
       {
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter Reponed Reason'));
        return null;
       }
        else
        {
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req.setComments(Comments);
        req.setAction('Reject');
        req.setWorkitemId(getWorkItemId(processId));
        Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process(req);
        //update objOpp;
        return redirectPage ;  
        }     
    }
VF Page: 
<apex:form standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="ApproveRejectController">>
<apex:page>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:outputField label="Servicing Location" value="{!objOpp.Servicing_Location_D__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField label="Sourcing Location" value="{!objOpp.Sourcing_Location__c}"/>
              <apex:inputtextarea label="Comments" rows="5" cols="100" value="{!Comments}"/> 
               <apex:inputField label="Reopened Reason" value="{!objOpp.Reopened_Reason__c}"/ > 
          </apex:pageBlockSection>

       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom"> 
           <apex:commandButton value="Approve" action="{!approve}"/>
           <apex:commandButton value="Reject" action="{!reject}" rerender="showmsg"/>
           <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>

   </apex:pageblock>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The value for Reopened_reason__c is a custom field in opportunity it is being modified in VF page where I need to update it back to opportunity.

Comment: Can you share your code.It would be easier to answer if you share what you  have written till now.